# Deleting/Removing .deb downloads and possible git cloned putty

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, deb

I am a new user of Ubuntu, and I've been playing around lately downloading and installing a few of my work platforms, one of which is also my code editor, sublime 3 (.deb).

- I was wondering after the installation, can I safely remove the .deb from my downloads folder?
- I also mistakenly started cloning putty from git, but then changed my mind and terminated the cloning.
- Is there a way that there's space being taken up by this terminated-clone?

Any documentation direction on this matter would be helpful.
I'm just trying to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can remove the .deb file.  It's the same as installing a program from windows -- you can safely remove the installer.  Ubuntu keeps track of how to uninstall the program in a separate place, so the .deb is not needed anymore.

The git directory is probably still taking up space with whatever was downloaded before you cancelled it.  You can safely delete it.  It'll be called whatever your repo was called.

Comment: im not able to find it however... is there a command to get that?

Comment: It's possible that it aborted and deleted the directory.  The easiest command to find anything is locate, e.g. locate *.deb or locate putty